# How add my alphabet to new book?

Tags: creative-writing, book

How joining a writers and a conscript creators (artifical language similar conlang).
How put my alphabet into writers book?

Many universums like StarWars, Bionicle ,Star Trek etc. have alphabet, languages etc. How put information to writers abut alphabets?

Comment: Welcome to Writers, Marwin! You might want to consider editing your question to make it clearer. In its current state, it is difficult to read, and difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Do you mean, How can I get text printed in a book in an alphabet that I made up? i.e. how mechanically to get a made-up alphabet into a computer file? Or are you asking how to discuss such an alphabet, from a literary point of view? Or what?

Comment: @Jay I believe the question is to convey the information. As in how to write the glossary. Then again, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Write your book.

Design your alphabet.

Include the page in the front or end matter of your book.

Publish.